# Proving that P <= NP

Tags: computer-science

As most people know, P = NP is unproven and seems unlikely to be true.  The proof would prove that P <= NP and NP <= P.  Only one of those is hard, though.

P <= NP is almost by definition true.  In fact, that's the only way that I know how to state that P <= NP.  It's just intuitive.  How would you prove that P <= NP?

Comment: @Travis how so?  If you can solve a problem in polynomial time (belongs to P), you can DEFINITELY verify it in polynomial time (belongs to NP).  The converse is not true.

Comment: @Nick that is the point.  P is a subset of NP, so P is contained in NP.  The statement is that NP is larger (or at least equal) to P, but P is completely contained within NP.

Comment: @Travis no.. If we can verify a solution in polynomial time, that puts it in the class NP.

Comment: @Travis, P is by definition <= NP. Any problem which can be solved on a TM in polynomial time can be solved on an NTM in polynomial time. This is true because all TMs are NTMs. Furthermore, being able to verify a solution in polynomial time is the definition of a problem being in NP.

Comment: @Travis What do you define as the class NP?  A problem falls under NP if it is verifiable in polynomial time.  Take, for example, finding a password.  The process of recovering a password based requires guessing all possible solutions.  But if I tell you the password, you can verify it in polynomial time.  Thus it is NP-Complete, thus it is in NP.

Comment: I assume that by "P <= NP" you mean "P ⊆ NP". :-) And you're right, it's true almost by definition: if you use the "given certificate, can verify" definition of NP, then you can just ignore certificate; if you use the "nonderministic machine" definition of NP, then just don't use any nondeterminism.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR yup, that's what I meant.  Just don't know how to use that character from my keyboard :)

Comment: @Gail, now you can just copy-paste that character from Shrevatsa's comment. :-)  P.S. and by the way your notion about complexity of finding a password is wrong.

Comment: @Gail, well, actually, if you're talking about recovering a password as about finding a key that decrypts something, then you're probably right.  Otherwise, if it's about cracking just an electronic lock on the wall, you're wrong.  There was a question on SO (but I can't find it).

Comment: @Pavel I was talking about it in terms of cryptography, but I don't actually see how an electronic lock on the wall is different.  With no prior knowledge, brute-force is the best option.  However, if I tell you a password, you can punch it into the electronic lock and verify it's correctness in polynomial time.

Comment: @Gail, that is an example that shows that nondeterministic Turing machines define the concept of NP in a more clear way than something about polynomial verification.  When I find that question, I'll leave the link here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you've essentially answered your own question in the comments: a problem which satisfies the definition of `P` also satisfies the definition of `NP`.

To quote wikipedia:

> All problems in P [are in NP] (For, given a certificate for a problem in P, we can ignore the certificate and just solve the problem in polynomial time. Alternatively, note that a deterministic Turing machine is also trivially a non-deterministic Turing machine that just happens to not use any non-determinism.)

The certificate it refers to is the polynomial-time verification of solution; as you say, you can solve a problem in `P` in polynomial time and you will therefore have a solution which has been verified in polynomial time and is therefore in `NP`.

Joey Adams' answer is the second explanation, in terms of solvability by (non)deterministic Turing machines. See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29) for a bit more explanation of that definition of `NP`.

I think what you should note here is that the fact that the proof is trivially simple doesn't mean it's not a proof. "By definition" is a perfectly valid logical step.

Answer (score 14):

Each problem in NP is solved by a nondeterministic Turing machine [in polynomial time]. (by definition*)

Each problem in P is solved by a deterministic Turing machine [in polynomial time]. (by definition)

Each deterministic Turing machine *is* a nondeterministic Turing machine as well. (obviously)

Hence each problem in P is solved by a nondeterministic Turing machine [in polynomial time].

Hence each problem in P is a problem in NP.  Hence P ⊆ NP.

---

*Let's read [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_%28complexity%29) on NP:

> In an equivalent formal definition, NP is the set of decision problems solvable in polynomial time by a non-deterministic Turing machine.

There's no need to introduce this stuff about polynomial verification into such a simple reasoning.

Comment: +1, though I'm not sure if one definition is really that much simpler than the other - one could also say there's no need to introduce stuff about determinism into reasoning as simple as polynomial time solving/verification.

Comment: @Jefromi, for *this* particular question it is simplier.  And for *some* other questions, perhaps, it's simplier as well.  One should not forget that there are several equivalent definition.

Comment: The equivalence of the definitions was the main thing I was trying to emphasize, along with the fact that "simpler" is a bit subjective.

Comment: Define "obviously". I think that there's also need (or would be more interesting in practice) to provide a proof that uses that fact that solutions to NP problems can be verified in polynomial time. The main advantage of solving the problem P vs NP would be to be able or not to find solutions to NP problems that run in polynomial time or just being able to check them in polynomial time. The non-deterministic model is unreal for now.

Comment: @PShved Most likely I am reading it wrong or misunderstanding the argument, but : `Each problem in NP is solved by a nondeterministic Turing machine [in polynomial time]` combined with `Each deterministic Turing machine is a nondeterministic Turing machine as well. (obviously)`; Would that not imply that each deterministic Turing machine would solve `Each problem in NP [in polynomial time]`? Could it perhaps be that you mixed that 2nd quoted statement up and instead meant: `Each nondeterministic Turing machine is a deterministic Turing machine as well`?

Answer (score 2):

A nondeterministic computer can simply not invoke its nondeterminism and act like a deterministic one, thus it can run P problems in polynomial time.  That's the best answer I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

A non-deterministic computer that solves a (NP) problem in polynomial time would also solve a P problem in polynomial time.

If we consider the imaginary approach of a Turing Machine that can take several paths at a decision to solve the NP problem in polynomial time, this behaviour must be enough to solve the P problem in P Time. Deterministic Turing machines are a case of simple (real) non-deterministic machines.

Answer (score 0):

Each problem in NP is solved by a nondeterministic Turing machine [in polynomial time]. (by definition*)

Each problem in P is solved by a deterministic Turing machine [in polynomial time]. (by definition)

Each deterministic Turing machine is a nondeterministic Turing machine as well. (obviously)

Hence each problem in P is solved by a nondeterministic Turing machine [in polynomial time].

Hence each problem in P is a problem in NP. Hence P ⊆ NP.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).